# Get SharePoint personal sites by Search Keyword Query

Tags: sharepoint, keyword-search

I try to retrieve the personal sites using keyword query by executing the following query but unfortunately I get only the SPO regular sites:

```
contentclass:STS_Site
```

Running contentclass:STS_Web doesn't work as well, even when stating the personal site path ("Path=....").

Does anyone know the proper keyword or Query property to bring them?
Or maybe is it something in the personal site configuration I should check?

Comment: this is personal site so you will not get all the personal site result as search result will be security trim base. try using web template query   webtemplate:"SPSPERS".
if you still need, create your own display template get all people and  in that  get properties personal site url and  display using display template.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/search/private-onedrive-results-not-included

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33939.sharepoint-server-2016-rtm-list-of-all-templates.aspx

Comment: @JayneshSharma thanks for helping! I already tried using webtemplate:"SPSPERS", still no results. i didn't mention that i'm testing it on variety of tenants and i have issues with **only one** of them, all others work fine and the personal sites retrieved by "contentclass:STS_Site". the issue is with one specific tenant. another thing, i do get the personal sites by CSOM, just not by the query above.is there another query i can try?